# postfix commands=5 causing mails not being sent

Tags: postfix

I'm able to send only mails using postfix but when it comes to sending mails to my own domain, postfix usually uses commands=6 which sends the email but sometimes it issues the **commands=5** which causes the mails to fail and i don't know where they end up.

The line in the below dump which causes the error -

```
disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
20FB641206: from=<admin@nvoids.com>, size=3149, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

The dump from postfix

```
Aug 10 07:29:49 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[1669634]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 10 07:29:49 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[1669634]: 20FB641206: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 10 07:29:49 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[1669637]: 20FB641206: message-id=<632614904.2235.1691652589133@ubuntu>
Aug 10 07:29:49 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[1669634]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Aug 10 07:29:49 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[533470]: 20FB641206: from=<admin@nvoids.com>, size=3149, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 10 07:29:49 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1669638]: 20FB641206: to=<emailid@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.251.167.27]:25, delay=0.54, d
elays=0/0/0.23/0.31, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1691652589 d7-20020a0cb2c7000000b0063d456fcd44si447714qvf.515 - gsmtp)
Aug 10 07:29:49 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[533470]: 20FB641206: removed
```

Postfix mostly uses the commands=6 which causes the mails being sent -

```
Aug 10 07:29:44 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[1669634]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 10 07:29:44 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[1669634]: 1B16341206: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 10 07:29:44 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[1669637]: 1B16341206: message-id=<835472293.2234.1691652584108@ubuntu>
Aug 10 07:29:44 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[1669634]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=2 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
Aug 10 07:29:44 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[533470]: 1B16341206: from=<admin@nvoids.com>, size=1043, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Aug 10 07:29:44 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1669638]: 1B16341206: to=<emailid@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.251.167.27]:25, delay=0.6, del
ays=0.01/0/0.23/0.36, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1691652584 o5-20020a05620a0d4500b00767507d715asi489272qkl.541 - gsmtp)
Aug 10 07:29:46 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1669639]: 1B16341206: to=<admin@nvoids.com>, relay=route1.mx.cloudflare.net[2606:4700:f5::c]:25, delay=2.6, delays=0.01
/0/0.19/2.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok)
Aug 10 07:29:46 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[533470]: 1B16341206: removed
```

the /etc/postfix/main.cf file -

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ubuntu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, smtp.domain.com, ubuntu, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

---

My bad i was only sending in some emails in which case it showed commands=5

In case the email was sent and copied to admin@nvoids.com it showed commands=6

Comment: In both examples, the mail was successfully sent, as the log entry`status=sent` indicates.

Comment: @AlexD in the first case it's not sent to admin@nvoids.com -  20FB641206: from=<admin@nvoids.com>, size=3149, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Comment: All 3 recipients where accepted (3 times `250 2.0.0 OK`) so maybe you were planning to have mail for your domain handled somewhere other than at `cloudflare.net`, but did not configure the MX records to say so?

Comment: my bad it's working fine see answer

Answer (score 2):

`commands=N` is not an error message, direct indication of success or failure; it's just for your information that during SMTP exchange there was N commands issued by the client, for you to roughly understand how long the conversation took.

Typical SMTP conversation looks like the following:

```
(connection established)
(server) 220 server.host.nam.me ESMTP blah-blah blah ...
(client) HELO [or EHLO] client.host.na.me
(server) 250-...
         250-...
         250 (proceed)
(client) MAIL FROM: [envelope sender email address]
(server) 250 (proceed)
(client) RCPT TO: [envelope recipient email address]
(server) 250 (proceed)
(client) DATA
(server) 250 (proceed end message with CRLF | "." | CRLF)
(client) message headers and data
(client) .
(server) 250 QUEUED as [some name]
(client) QUIT
(server) 221 Goodbye!
(connection terminated)
```

If you count how many times client did something, you'd find it's 5: `HELO`, `MAIL FROM`, `RCPT TO`, `DATA` and `QUIT`. Those are commands, and as you see, typically it takes 5 commands to send a mail. In some cases it might be more: client may authenticate, or have several `RCPT TO` commands (to add more recipients for this message), or whatever. I believe this is your case: additional recipient `admin@...` causes extra `RCPT TO` command to be issued.

Also in some cases server or client may interrupt the conversation early. For example, if server doesn't want to relay mail with certain envelope sender address, it may indicate error instead of 250 (accepted) reply code after receiving `MAIL FROM`, and client may reply with `QUIT` to that, resulting in a conversation taking less than 5 commands. So if you see a number less that 5 there, it *may* be the indication of a failure (but *not always*).

The only *definitive* indication of the delivery status of a message is the word after the `status=` in the log line:

```
Aug 10 07:29:46 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1669639]: 1B16341206: to=<admin@nvoids.com>, relay=route1.mx.cloudflare.net[2606:4700:f5::c]:25, delay=2.6, delays=0.01/0/0.19/2.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok)
```

This mail was `sent`, which really means, the `route1.mx.cloudflare.net` server replied with `250 (ok) ...` after the last dot in the DATA command during the SMTP conversation. There may be other status here, which mean their corresponding statuses, and it is how Postfix indicates problems with the delivery.